# How do I make my Firebase project point to a different set of cloud functions?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I had a Firebase backend that was associated with a set of cloud functions, call it CF1. Since I had been working on these cloud functions for years, I decided to recreate the project with a fresh skeleton and port my functions into it, call this CF2. I now want to make my Firebase project point to CF2. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean by "point to"?  It would help if you edit the question to explain in more detail what doesn't work the way you expect, and what you tried already.

Comment: Why don’t you simply redeploy your Cloud Functions from CF1 project to CF2 project? If you have lost the code you can find it in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec do I do that by running `firebase init` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general way to make Cloud Functions in one project respond to events in another project.

What **is** possible is to take the code of the Cloud Functions directory in your first project (typically `functions/index.js`), copy them over to the directory of your second project, and run `firebase deploy` there,

Comment: Yea I guess that's simpler. Maybe I was overthinking this. Thanks